# Django with chartkick

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts, chartkick

I'm trying to make charts with Chartkick on Django app. The thing is i followed instruction on [their page](https://github.com/mher/chartkick.py) but i got error saying below, Is there anyone who knows how to achieve getting chart on this?

> chartkick' is not a valid tag library: Template library chartkick not
>   found, tried `django.templatetags.chartkick,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.chartkick,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.chartkick`

in my html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Тайлан{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  {% load chartkick %}
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
  <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="test">Тайлан гаргах тест сонгох</label>
      <select id="test" name="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Сорил 001</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Сонгох</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="chart">
        {% line_chart data %}
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/chartkick.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tespa', #main app
    #thirdparty app
    'chartkick',
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    chartkick.js(),   
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Probably need to add the relevant portions of your settings.py to your question.

Comment: Based on what you've written, most probably it's because you might not have imported chartkick in your settings.py. Django is unable to find "chartkick" templatetag, most common reason for this would be non inclusion of the library.

Comment: Chartkick is already added in settings.py, plus adding `chartkick.js()` in `staticfiles_dirs` gives error saying 'module' object has no attribute 'js'

Comment: @Brandon i added settings.py

Comment: That `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting seems very odd to me. I would try changing it to `chartkick/js`. I'm not sure why they decided not to just use a `static` directory.

Comment: @Brandon but it's not issue with the error right? or is it with the version of Django.1.8

Comment: They have a `.js()` method in their init, which returns the path of their `/js` directory, but that's a rather odd way of distributing those files in my opinion. I guess you could try adding that method as a callable string: `'chartclick.js'` in `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: but when i add `chartkick.js()` into STATICFILES_DIRS it gives me error and i can't start server it gives this error 

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'js'`

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you - their way of adding the js directory is fubar. For one, I would file a bug against the project on Github. Two, I would fork their code and add the js directory to a static directory so Django will automatically find it, and also collect it properly when `collectstatic` is run. If they simply followed the Django convention for distributing static media with shared applications, you wouldn't have to deal with this issue.

Comment: Ok, that's nice to hear

Comment: Yeah, I've never once seen static media added that way since I started working with Django in 2008. I maintain two open source Django projects, and I just use the standard way of distributing static files, which is to place them into a directory named "static". This allows the staticfiles app to automatically find them for local development, and the collectstatic command to find them for production deployment. Example: https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable/tree/master/adminsortable/static/adminsortable

Comment: Yeah, I actually go with directory named 'static' too. So currently there is no way i use chartkick on my django project, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this in your template:
{% load chartkick %}

Add this:
{{ chart }}

And do not forget to add the script.